# How to properly comment on the methods in c?

Tags: c, comments

How to properly comment on the methods in c?

Is there something like in Java?

```
/*
*Returns the value of the sin(x)
*
*@param..?
.@return..?
.

?
?
```

Thank you for your advice.
Than you..

Comment: No methods in C (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "proper way to comment" -- comments don't care, and as long as you're meeting the compiler requirements, they don't care either.

What you're really asking about, I think, is how to comment in order to use some external tool (such as doxygen). This is not something that is important to the language, but rather to the tool -- and you need to read your tool's documentation to know what it expects.

Comment: Maybe @JaLe29 is asking if there's an accepted commenting standard or convention.  This is company dependent.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey my assumption that the purpose of the question is related to use of external tools is his example shows things one would typically to in Java in order to use doxygen to produce documentation. His mention of Java, coupled with the doxygen syntax of the comment was a good tip-off.

Comment: @mah You're very astute.  That went over my head.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I like to comment a function definition:

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * @brief   
 * @author  
 * @date    
 * @return  
 * @arg
 * @note     
 *
 *****************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

See there are two types of comments

1. `//` For Single line ( For short important info related to variables
2. `/* */` For multiline ( Used basically for description )

How to use it

```
/*

This is a Addition function. It takes two variables of int type and yields the addition of it.

*/

int add(int a, int b){

 int c = 0; // Variable to store result
 return c; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides some guidelines at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx

- Place the comment on a separate line, not at the end of a line of code.
- Begin comment text with an uppercase letter.
- End comment text with a period.
- Insert one space between the comment delimiter (//) and the comment text, as shown in the following example.

Ultimately, like @Mah said, if you are the only one on the project, it doesn't matter. Otherwise, some kind of convention should be agreed upon beforehand and adhered to for readability.